# Watin SelectedItem on a selectlist returns null

Tags: drop-down-menu, watin

Prior to installing Watin 2, we were using the SelectedItem property on a dropdown/select list which would return the text of the current item selected in the list of values. After upgrading to Watin  2.1, the same method returns null.

Following is my observation:
HasSelectedItems is false
SelectedItems.Count = 0
GetAttribute("selected") returns null
AllContents has all the items in the select list and the AllContents.Count = 30 (since I have 30 items)

Is there a new way to get the current item in a dropdown/simple select list?
Thanks,
DM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-copy the Microsoft.MSHTML.DLL and it works like magic now. 
Will be running a variety of tests on IE9 with VS 2010. I guess it should all be good now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IE 9? If so you will probably need [WatiN 2.1](http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-1-0-1196/) released week ago.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I am using IE9 with VS2010. I upgraded to Watin 2.1 after which I noticed this issue. Prior to Watin 2 (Final Release) these methods were working as expected.